# TCL / TCLSH no such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, tcl

I'm trying to build a software called Slicer3 on Windows 7 which features a "super build".
It's a All-in-one TCL Script to checkout and build Slicer3.

I ran CYGWIN and navigated til the correct directory, then ran the script and got:

```
$ ./Slicer3-svn/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl
couldn't read file "./Slicer3-svn/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl": no such file or directory
```

Obviously I am sure that the file exists and I gave it 777 permission. I'm running cygwin as admin.

The beginning of the tcl file's content is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# the next line restarts using tclsh \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"
```

So I tried commenting out line 3 and running directly

```
$ tclsh ./Slicer3-svn/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl
```

but got the same error.
Any idea?

Comment: Just double-checking: you're using a cygwin build of Tcl? If not, you'll need a windows-style filename (with backslashes instead of forward-slashes).

Comment: can you *cat ./Slicer3-svn/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl*?

Comment: might not matter on cygwin, but is the tcl script saved in Dos format (\r\n end of line) instead of unix (\n end of line)?

Comment: I wondered about the line endings as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description: TCLSH couldn't read file: no such file or directory.
Possible reason: TCLSH under CYGWIN does not resolve windows PATH's properly, and cannot find the files.
Workaround: move the script within the CYGWIN path.

just moving the script to a "simpler" path works for me. I'm not that sure about the reason, neither how to solve this misbehaviour.

Answer (score 4):

I will try to help troubleshooting as much as I can:

Determine if you have tclsh installed and it is in the PATH:

```
$ tclsh
```

Determine if tclsh works for a simple script:

```
$ echo puts hello > hello.tcl; tclsh hello.tcl
```

Determine if the script exists and readable:

```
$ cat ./Slicer3-svn/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl
$ cd ./Slicer3-svn/Scripts
$ cat getbuildtest.tcl
```

As far as line-ending (DOS CRLF vs. Unix LF):

```
$ cd ./Slicer3-svn/Scripts
$ sed 's/\r\n/\n/g' getbuildtest.tcl > getbuildtest_new.tcl
$ tclsh getbuildtest_new.tcl
```

This way, we can narrow down the problem, should any of the steps failed.

Comment: 1) OK
$ tclsh
%
2) OK
$ echo puts hello > hello.tcl; tclsh hello.tcl
% hello
3) cat prints the file, in both case
4) I need first to chmod 777 getbuildtest_new.tcl, but the result is the same

Comment: I can disable the third line of my script:
# exec tclsh "$0" "$@"
So it will be interpreted as TCL.
Result:
$ ./Slicer3/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl
./Slicer3/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl: line 25: proc: command not found
./Slicer3/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl: line 26: global: command not found
./Slicer3/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl: line 60: puts: command not found
./Slicer3/Scripts/getbuildtest.tcl: line 61: syntax error near expected token ‘}’
Quite expected since those aren't TCL commands. At least the file exists and is readable!

Comment: My script path, on windows is:
C:\Users\Hugues\Documents\DEV\LIB\Slicer\Slicer3\Scripts
My script path, seen from cygwin is:
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/Hugues/My Documents/DEV/LIB/Slicer/Slicer3/Scripts
My script path, seen from the tclsh shell, is:
$ tclsh
% pwd
C:/Documents and Settings//My Documents//LIB/Slicer/Slicer3/Scripts
(note the double // and missing directories)

Comment: When I run tclsh and run interactively the script:
$ cd Slicer3/Scripts
$ tclsh
% exec getbuildtest.tcl
couldn't execute "getbuildtest.tcl": no such file or directory

So it seems like it has something to do with Relative Path and Absolute Path, and the way TCLSH tries to read something within the CYGWIN file tree.

Comment: I'm correct that it has to do with the PATH.
I moved the whole thing to \home in CYGWIN and TCLSH finds the script.